# Collapse a div with delay

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a div with same elegance as it is expanded. But it collapses immediately or abruptly.

**Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function scrollToElement(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
            time = typeof(time) != 'undefined' ? time : 1000;
            verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
            element = $(selector);
            offset = element.offset();
            offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;
            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: offsetTop
            }, time);
        }
        $("#contact-container").hide();
        $(".dropcontact").click(function(){
            $("#contact-container").toggle();
            scrollToElement("#contact-container",500,140);
    });
});
```

In the above code .dropcontact is a link.

Comment: Yes, slideToggle, not slideUp/Down. I need to read the api again :) http://jsfiddle.net./xhPLC/1/

Comment: yes, slidetoggle worked

Answer (score 0):

Is this you want?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".header").click(function () {
            $("#mydiv").animate({
                height: ["toggle", "swing"]
            }, {
                duration: 500,
                complete: function () {

                }
            });

        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h4 class="header">
    Click Here</h4>
<div id="mydiv">
   some test data
   <br/>
   some test data
   some test data
   <br/>
   some test data
   some test data
   <br/>
   some test data
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing parameters "slow" or milliseconds (like 400) will make it hide slowly

```
$("#contact-container").hide("slow");
```